# ps -a fails to find a process which is running

Tags: process, osx, ps, htop

I could find a process named typora from `htop`

[image]

but I cannot trace it from ps or pstree

```
$ ps -a | grep -i typora
 9696 ttys003    0:00.01 grep -i typora

$ pstree | grep -i typora 
 |     |--- 09713 me grep -i typora
 |--= 00258 me /Applications/Typora.app/Contents/MacOS/Typora -psn_0_40970
```

How could I find it from command ps.

Comment: Have you try `ps -efl | grep -i typora`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `ps` manual on macOS (my emphasis):

> `-a`
>
> Display information about other users' processes as well as your own.  **This will skip any processes which do not have a controlling terminal, unless the `-x` option is also specified.**

Applications that are running on macOS without a controlling terminal, such as windowed Finder applications, will not be listed by `ps -a`.  To list these, use `ps -ax`.

Or, you may may use the `-A` or `-e` option:

> `-A`
>
> Display information about other users' processes, including those without controlling terminals.
>
> `-e`
>
> Identical to `-A`.

If you are looking for information about a process with a particular *name*, consider using `pgrep` instead:

```
pgrep Typora
```

(note that case matters, unless you use `pgrep -i`)

To signal a process with a particular name, use `pkill` rather than trying to `grep` the output of `ps`.

See the manuals for `pgrep` and `pkill`.

Also, even though this was not part of your question, `pstree` has a `-s` option to show only the branches of the process tree that contains processes with a particular name.

Comment: Or use POSIX `ps -A`. MacOS  being a UNIX certified system, I'd expect `ps -e` would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: add to `ps` switch `H`. From man:  `H Show threads as if they were processes`.

Long answer is down.

I am aware that this, 5 years old, question is answered and answer is accepted, but, from one hand I am not very satisfied with it and on second hand let me bring variant, which, I hope, will be helpful.

`htop` is showing processes along with their threads, which can be easily checked by pressing `t` in interactive mode or initially by option "`-t --tree Show the tree view`".

As `typora` is not free now, then as example I had used command `mate-terminal`. First call creates process,  while subsequent calls creates threads from first.
So, after simple `htop` we have

[image]

After pressing `t`

[image]

When we used command `ps axu` , for example, we see only first process and we cannot see threads, but they are listed under `/proc/<pid>/task/`.

[image]

To see also threads we can use `H` switch in BSD stile, so `ps axuH` will show process with its threads and now we can see the same picture, which we have in `htop`

[image]

Described behavior is not necessary and is inherent to `mate-terminal` and, as I guess, to `typora`. For example each call of `konsole` crates new process and is seen as under `htop`, so by `ps axu`.

Answer is tested in debian 11.6.